# Unknown HTML facade in Blade template

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-facade, laravel-5

I am trying to add bootstrap template to my Laravel project . Presently i am using `Laravel 5.2` and it gives the following error.

> FatalErrorException in 309d94eeb37e8691a8ebbde32df9440f6af8f59a.php line 11:
>   Class 'HTML' not found

**My app.php**

```
<?php

return [
    'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),
    'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),
    'url' => 'http://localhost',
    'timezone' => 'UTC',
    'locale' => 'en',
    'fallback_locale' => 'en',
    'key' => env('APP_KEY'),

    'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',

    'log' => env('APP_LOG', 'single'),


    'providers' => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
        Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
    ],

 'aliases' => [

        'App'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
        'Artisan'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
        'Auth'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
        'Blade'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
        'Cache'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
        'Config'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
        'Cookie'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
        'Crypt'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
        'DB'        => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
        'Eloquent'  => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
        'Event'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
        'File'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
        'Gate'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
        'Hash'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
        'Lang'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
        'Log'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
        'Mail'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
        'Password'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
        'Queue'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
        'Redirect'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
        'Redis'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
        'Request'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
        'Response'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
        'Route'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
        'Schema'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
        'Session'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
        'Storage'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
        'URL'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
        'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
        'View'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
        'Form'      => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
        'Html'      => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,

    ],

];
```

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "laravelcollective/html": "5.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

generated html content

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Fashion World</title>
<link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/fashion/public/css/bootstrap.css">

<link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/fashion/public/css/style.css">

<link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/fashion/public/css/memenu.css">

<link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/fashion/public/css/popuo-box.css">

<link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/fashion/public/css/flexslider.css">



<script src="http://localhost/fashion/public/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://localhost/fashion/public/js/imagezoom.js"></script>

<script src="http://localhost/fashion/public/js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>

<script src="http://localhost/fashion/public/js/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>

<script src="http://localhost/fashion/public/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://localhost/fashion/public/js/memenu.js"></script>

<script src="http://localhost/fashion/public/js/responsiveslides.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://localhost/fashion/public/js/simpleCart.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://localhost/fashion/public/js/validation-lib.js"></script>

<script src="http://localhost/fashion/public/js/validations.js"></script>


<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<!-- Custom Theme files -->
<!--theme-style-->
<!--//theme-style-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Fashion Mania Responsive web template, Bootstrap Web Templates, Flat Web Templates, Andriod Compatible web template,
Smartphone Compatible web template, free webdesigns for Nokia, Samsung, LG, SonyErricsson, Motorola web design" />
<script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>
<!-- start menu -->
<script>$(document).ready(function(){$(".memenu").memenu();});</script>
<!-- slide -->
   <script>
    $(function () {
      $("#slider").responsiveSlides({
        auto: true,
        speed: 500,
        namespace: "callbacks",
        pager: true,
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<!--header-->
<div class="header">
    <div class="header-top">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-4 world">

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 logo">
          <img src="http://localhost/fashion/public/images/logo.png">
                    <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt=""></a>
                </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4 header-left">
                    <p class="log"><a href="account.html"  >Login</a>
                        <span>or</span><a  href="account.html"  >Signup</a></p>
                    <div class="cart box_1">
                        <a href="checkout.html">
                        <h3> <div class="total">
                            <span class="simpleCart_total"></span></div>
                            <img src="images/cart.png" alt=""/></h3>
                        </a>
                        <p><a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_empty">Empty Cart</a></p>

                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
            </div>
                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="head-top">
                <div class="col-sm-2 number">
                    <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></i>08558 - 221048</span>
                </div>
         <div class="col-sm-8 h_menu4">
                <ul class="memenu skyblue">
                      <li class=" grid"><a  href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                      <li><a  href="#">Men</a>
                        <div class="mepanel">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col1">
                                <div class="h_nav">
                                    <h4>All Clothing</h4>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="products.html">Shirts</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="products.html">Shorts</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="products.html">Formal Shirts</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="products.html">Trousers & Chinos</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="products.html">T-Shirts</a></li>

                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col1">
                                <div class="h_nav">
                                    <h4>Footwear</h4>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="products.html">Formal Shoes</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="products.html">Sports Shoes</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="products.html">Casual Shoes</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="products.html">Running Shoes</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="products.html">Slippers</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="products.html">Sandals</a></li>

                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col1">
                                <div class="h_nav">
                                    <h4>Popular Brands</h4>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="products.html">Nike</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="products.html">Flying Machine</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="products.html">Wrangler</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="products.html">Denim</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="products.html">Levis</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="products.html">Pepe Jeans</a></li>
                    <li><a href="products.html">Reebook</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="products.html">Puma</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="grid"><a  href="#">  Women</a>
                        <div class="mepanel">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col1">
                                <div class="h_nav">
                                    <h4>All Clothing</h4>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="products.html">Shirts & Tops</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="products.html">Kurtas & Kurties</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="products.html">Sarees</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="products.html">Swimwear</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="products.html">Night-Suits</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="products.html">T-Shirts</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="products.html">Jeans</a></li>

                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col1">
                                <div class="h_nav">
                                    <h4>Footwear</h4>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="products.html">Heels</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="products.html">Flats</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="products.html">Sports Shoes</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="products.html">Casual Shoes</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="products.html">Running Shoes</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="products.html">Slippers</a></li>

                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col1">
                                <div class="h_nav">
                                    <h4>Popular Brands</h4>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="products.html">Nike</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="products.html">Flying Machine</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="products.html">Wrangler</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="products.html">Denim</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="products.html">Levis</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="products.html">Pepe Jeans</a></li>
                                                                                <li><a href="products.html">Reebook</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="products.html">Puma</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                </li>
                <li><a class="color6" href="contact.html">Conact</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2 search">
            <a class="play-icon popup-with-zoom-anim" href="#small-dialog"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"> </i> </a>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
            <!---pop-up-box---->
      {<script src="http://localhost/fashion/public/js/modernizr.custom.min.js"></script>
}
                    <!---//pop-up-box---->
                <div id="small-dialog" class="mfp-hide">
                <div class="search-top">
                        <div class="login">
                            <input type="submit" value="">
                            <input type="text" value="Type something..." onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '';}">
                        </div>
                        <p> Shopping</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                 <script>
                        $(document).ready(function() {
                        $('.popup-with-zoom-anim').magnificPopup({
                            type: 'inline',
                            fixedContentPos: false,
                            fixedBgPos: true,
                            overflowY: 'auto',
                            closeBtnInside: true,
                            preloader: false,
                            midClick: true,
                            removalDelay: 300,
                            mainClass: 'my-mfp-zoom-in'
                        });

                        });
                </script>
    <!---->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--banner-->
<div class="banner">
    <div class="col-sm-3 banner-mat">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="images/ba11.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 matter-banner">
        <div class="slider">
            <div class="callbacks_container">
                <ul class="rslides" id="slider">
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/11.jpg" alt="">
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <img src="images/22.jpg" alt="">
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <img src="images/33.jpg" alt="">
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 banner-mat">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="images/ba2.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
</div>
<!--//banner-->
<!--content-->
<div class="content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content-top">
            <h1>Recent Products</h1>
            <div class="content-top1">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-md2">
                    <div class="col-md1 simpleCart_shelfItem">
                        <a href="single.html">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="images/pi.png" alt="" />
                        </a>
                        <h3><a href="single.html">Tops</a></h3>
                        <div class="price">
                                <h5 class="item_price">$300</h5>
                                <a href="#" class="item_add">Add To Cart</a>
                                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-md2">
                    <div class="col-md1 simpleCart_shelfItem">
                        <a href="single.html">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="images/pi2.png" alt="" />
                        </a>
                        <h3><a href="single.html">T-Shirt</a></h3>
                        <div class="price">
                                <h5 class="item_price">$300</h5>
                                <a href="#" class="item_add">Add To Cart</a>
                                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-md2">
                    <div class="col-md1 simpleCart_shelfItem">
                        <a href="single.html">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="images/pi4.png" alt="" />
                        </a>
                        <h3><a href="single.html">Shirt</a></h3>
                        <div class="price">
                                <h5 class="item_price">$300</h5>
                                <a href="#" class="item_add">Add To Cart</a>
                                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-md2">
                    <div class="col-md1 simpleCart_shelfItem">
                        <a href="single.html">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="images/pi1.png" alt="" />
                        </a>
                        <h3><a href="single.html">Tops</a></h3>
                        <div class="price">
                                <h5 class="item_price">$300</h5>
                                <a href="#" class="item_add">Add To Cart</a>
                                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-top1">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-md2">
                    <div class="col-md1 simpleCart_shelfItem">
                        <a href="single.html">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="images/pi3.png" alt="" />
                        </a>
                        <h3><a href="single.html">Shirt</a></h3>
                        <div class="price">
                                <h5 class="item_price">$300</h5>
                                <a href="#" class="item_add">Add To Cart</a>
                                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-md2">
                    <div class="col-md1 simpleCart_shelfItem">
                        <a href="single.html">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="images/pi5.png" alt="" />
                        </a>
                        <h3><a href="single.html">T-Shirt</a></h3>
                        <div class="price">
                                <h5 class="item_price">$300</h5>
                                <a href="#" class="item_add">Add To Cart</a>
                                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-md2">
                    <div class="col-md1 simpleCart_shelfItem">
                        <a href="single.html">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="images/pi6.png" alt="" />
                        </a>
                        <h3><a href="single.html">Jeans</a></h3>
                        <div class="price">
                                <h5 class="item_price">$300</h5>
                                <a href="#" class="item_add">Add To Cart</a>
                                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-md2">
                    <div class="col-md1 simpleCart_shelfItem">
                        <a href="single.html">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="images/pi7.png" alt="" />
                        </a>
                        <h3><a href="single.html">Tops</a></h3>
                        <div class="price">
                                <h5 class="item_price">$300</h5>
                                <a href="#" class="item_add">Add To Cart</a>
                                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--//content-->
<!--footer-->
<div class="footer">
    <div class="container">

    <div class="footer-bottom">
        <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-3 footer-bottom-cate">
                    <h6>Categories</h6>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Men Clothing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Men Foot wear</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Women Clothing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Women Foot wear</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 footer-bottom-cate">
                    <h6>Shoppee</h6>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 footer-bottom-cate">
                    <h6>Top Brands</h6>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Nike</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Flying Machine</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Wrangler</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Denim</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Levis</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Pepe Jeans</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Reebook</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Puma</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 footer-bottom-cate cate-bottom">
                    <h6>Registered Address</h6>

                                        <p style="color: #B8B8B8">1st Floor</p>
                    <p style="color: #B8B8B8">CCC Block,JNTUA</p>
                    <p style="color: #B8B8B8">Anantapur</P>
                    <p style="color: #B8B8B8">Andhra Pradesh, India</p>
                    <p style="color: #B8B8B8">Mobile : 9618984961</p>

                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                <p class="footer-class"> © 2015 Fashion World All Rights Reserved | Design by Msitians </p>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!--//footer-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use exact same case as defined in alias. You used `Html`, so in blade it should be also `Html` and not `HTML` or `htmL`

Comment: whenever i do as u said it displays   { } { } { } { } { } { } { } { } { } { } { } { } { } { } { } all braces and other html content

Comment: IF you are using this package look at documentation (or also on Laravel 5.2 documentation) - you should use `{!! Html::style('css/bootstrap.css') !!}` and not `{{!!HTML::style('css/bootstrap.css')!!}}`

Comment: ,I removed those extra braces. But it doesn't accessing the css and js files .it just displays normal html content

Comment: What do you mean? This SHOULD display in page source HTML content. Make sure paths for JS and CSS are valid

Comment: Show source of generated HTML

Comment: i updated the question with generated html source code

Comment: As I said you should probably read documentation. Code looks fine. Probably you need to use `asset` function http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-asset to get url for valid path

Comment: From what I may capture... Your question may very well be about using actual objects as if you were calling Facades anywhere else like creating an Html Factory object that you expose as Html facade within your template else it could be that you are talking about file inclusion. Honestly your question is still ambiguous as it misled me from what I came here looking for as per Google search. Please fix